# Errors when inserting records into BigQuery with Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm running into an issue when i'm inserting rows into bigquery

The error is simply 'backend error' and nothing else

I'm taking 10k rows at a time, and doing an insert, after about 40k records are inserted I get 'backend error'

I'm using python and inserting with this code

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
_bigquery_client = bigquery.Client()
rows=[[1,2],[3,4]]
_bigquery_client.insert_rows(rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [backend error](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#errortable) is due to temporary server failure such as a network connection problem or a server overload.

> backendError | 500 or 503
>
> This error returns when there is a temporary
> server failure such as a network connection problem or a server
> overload.

These errors are being encountered from time to time but with a very low ratio which should comply to the [BigQuery SLA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sla). The fix for this is to just retry the insert.